# MARIADB variables in SELECT statements POSTGRES equivelent

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In mariadb/mysql I can use variables in the following way to perform calculations in a select statement. In this simple instance, I create a range of dates and use variables to calculate a simple opening balance and closing balance, with a payment of 10 each day.

```
with RECURSIVE dates as (
select '2017-11-01' as `dt`
union all
select adddate(dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 from dates
where dt < CURDATE()
)

select 
@vardate:=d.dt
, @openbal
, @payment:= 10
, @closebal:= @openbal+@payment
, @openbal:=@closebal
from dates d;
```

gives the results....

```
╔══════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗  
║ "ac_date"    ║ "open_bal" ║ "trans_total" ║ "close_bal" ║  
╠══════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣  
║ "2017-11-01" ║ "0"        ║ "10"          ║ "10"        ║  
║ "2017-11-02" ║ "10"       ║ "10"          ║ "20"        ║  
║ "2017-11-03" ║ "20"       ║ "10"          ║ "30"        ║  
...
```

Using this technique I can perform simple calculations on the fly in a select statement. My question is, is it possible to use variables in this way in a PL/pgSQL function or is there an alternative method I am overlooking?

Comment: You don't need variables for that in Postgres. You can simply use window functions (and since when can you do `with recursive` in MySQL?)

Comment: would you mind showing me how to achieve the result in the question using window functions? I think it might help conceptually. The query I am working from produces a loan schedule calculating daily interest and uses the technique described extensively.

Comment: You need to explain how the output is created. Your payment is set to `1` yet the output shows an increase of `10`. Alos where does `trans_total` come from? I can't derived that from the variables either

Comment: apologies for the 1/10 error. typo.. Updated. Thanks for the response. That has definitely got me onto the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how that statement works in MariaDB, but this seems to do the same thing:

```
with vars (openbal, payment) as (
  values (0, 10)
), balance as (
  select t.dt::date as ac_date, 
         openbal, 
         payment,
         sum(payment) over  (order by t.dt) as close_bal
  from vars, 
       generate_series(date '2017-11-01', current_date, interval '1' day ) as t(dt)
)
select ac_date, 
       openbal + lag(close_bal) over (order by ac_date) as open_bal,
       payment,
       close_bal
from balance;
```

In general to get a running total you use `sum() over (order by ...)`  in SQL. To access values from a previous row, you use the `lag()` function.

The two CTEs are needed because window functions can't be nested.

To generate a list of rows, use `generate_series()` in Postgrse.